# Printer issue Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: printing

Ubuntu 16.04 we set the number of copies 2 by default in printer settings. After we print the sheet on browser it goes to number of copies is one. What we need to do to print 2 copies?

Comment: You need to setup printer to print 2 copies always permanently? For example you print some 3 pages with 2 copies and then you command to print something another (2 pages) and printer must print it in 2 copies again.. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Open http://localhost:631 in a browser and go to the adminitration page for your printer. Then to manage printers and find the configuration option. Set the amount of copies there.

Comment: there is no configration option